# Get date in current time zone in objective - c?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSArray *fromD = [setFreeHour valueForKey:@"fromDate"];
NSString *fromdate = fromD[0];
NSDateFormatter *fromDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[fromDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *fromDate = [fromDateFormatter dateFromString:fromdate];
```

Results :

- In fromdate = 2018-07-24 11:41:25
- In fromDate = 2018-07-24 06:11:25 +0000

So how can i get both the date (fromdate and fromDate) equal or fromDate in Local Time Zone

Comment: You only have one date. Where is the 2nd date?

Comment: one is fromdate and other is fromDate @rmaddy

Comment: `fromdate` is a `String`. `fromDate` is a `Date` created from the `String`. So there is only one date. There is nothing to compare.

Comment: I would highly recommend using variable names that are more obvious. Having two entirely different variables that differ only by a capital letter half way through is being intentionally obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` values represent a point in time irrespective of the local interpretation of that point, i.e. when it is midday where you are it is midnight somewhere else - same point in time, different local interpretation.

So when you compare dates you convert them to the equivalent `NSDate` representation first.

To convert a date/time in text format to `NSDate` format you use `NSDateFormatter`. If there is no time zone specified in the text format you are using, or you do set the formatters time zone property, then your instance of `NSDateFormatter` will use the current local time zone set on the machine it is running on. E.g. If your code the time difference between the text format and the resultant `NSDate` value is 5 hours, so we can deduce the machine you used is in a local time zone 5 hours ahead of UTC/GMT

> I need to compare these date. So how can i get both the date equal?

You do exactly what you did, convert your text format to an `NSDate` value and then compare those values using the methods provided by `NSDate`. That is you don't "get both equal", you convert each to its point in time and compare those.

HTH

BTW: It is inadvisable to use variable names, `fromdate` and `fromDate`, which differ in (minor) capitalisation, it makes the code hard to read, debug and maintain.

**After question edit**

You have edited the question to further ask how your `NSDate` `fromDate` can be shown in the local time zone. The answer is the same as converting text format to `NSDate` - use an `NSDateFormatter, indeed you can use the exact same one. Insteading of using the method`dateFromString:`you used to get from text format you use`stringFromDate:` to convert to text format. The same rules about time zones mentioned above apply.

If you simply `NSLog()` an `NSDate` value you will get the point in time it represents in UTC/GMT.

Comment: @Mukie - I'm sorry, but I've no idea what formatted code you are asking for. If you are asking for code I have written there is none, I've simply tried to explain how date/ties work. Is there something in the answer that is unclear to you? If there is make it clear what and I'll see if I can make it clearer.

Comment: @Mukie - Updated to answer the question you added in your edit.